# scan specific udp port for local network

Tags: networking, raspbian, nmap, wireshark

So I have a Prometheus server which I use to capture input from port 512 UDP, I have it open, but now I have a problem checking which 512 UDP port on my network is the sender. I tried reading the nmap and tshark documentation, but I couldn't find what I wanted. In addition, I don't have access to another server that is the sender, so I need to do a scan from the recipient to find out which one is the sender

Comment: What can a scan tell you? Besides, what is your question exactly? Update the question with details, please. What is it that you're looking for? What is the problem?

Comment: Since you mention `tshark`, I believe you want to trace traffic that goes to UDP port 512. If so, try `tcpdump -n udp port 512`. The `-n` option prevents reverse DNS lookups. You can add `-i` if you want to listen on a different NIC than the first one.

Comment: @berndbausch thx sir, the commands you suggested worked well